# How to resolve circular reference between dataframe columns in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, circular-reference

I have a multiindex dataframe with indexes `Date` and `Symbol`. The dataframe has around 10 million rows. The dataframe has a column `Entry_signal` with `True` or `False` values, another column `Initial_stop` with number values, and another column `Low` with number values as well. Based on the content of these three columns I want to calculate another three columns: `Stop_level`, `Position`, `Exit_signal`. These should be calculated based on the following logic:

```
data['Entry_signal'] = # True or False
data['Initial_stop'] = # numbers
data['Low'] = # numbers

data['Stop_level'] = np.where(data['Position'] == True,
                              np.maximum(data['Stop_level'].shift(1),
                                         data['Initial_stop']),
                              data['Initial_stop'])

data['Exit_signal'] = np.where(data['Low'] < data.groupby('Symbol')['Stop_level'].shift(1),
                               True,
                               False)

data['Position'] = np.where(data['Exit_signal'] == True,
                            False,
                            np.where(data['Entry_signal'] == True,
                                     True,
                                     data.groupby('Symbol')['Position'].shift(1)))

data['Position'] = data.groupby('Symbol')['Position'].ffill()
```

Now `Stop_level` raises error because it needs a `Position`. If I put `Position` at the beginning, it raises error because it needs `Exit_signal`. If I put `Exit_signal` at the beginning, it raises error because it needs `Stop_level`. And so on. How can I make this logic work?

Answer (score 0):

Write it out on a scrap of paper:

1. `Stop_level` is a function of: `Position`, `Stop_level`,
   `Initial_stop`.
2. `Exit_signal` is a function of: `Low`, `Symbol`, `Stop_level`.
3. `Position` is a function of: `Exit_signal`, `Entry_signal`,
   `Symbol`, `Position`.

The current order does not work because `Stop_level` requires `Position`. Putting `Position` first doesn't work since it requires `Exit_signal`. Putting `Exit_signal` first doesn't work as it requires `Stop_level`. This exhausts all your options.

Therefore, you need to define logic which can actually be implemented.

Comment: You are right. Actually I want `Stop_level` to be the rolling max of `Initial_stop` (starting at the first `True` `Position` value) in case `Position` is `True`.  Otherwise, `Stop_level` should equal `Initial_stop`. I try to rephrase the question.